# Primefaces datatable paginator is not affected by page's layout changes

Tags: jsf, layout, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 4.0 Datatable with a paginator. The table lies right under an accordionPanel which can expand or collapse, affecting the layout of the page.
Unfortunately, the paginator of the datatable doesn't move when the accordion animation is performed.

[**BEFORE EXPANDING the accordion:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMMtw.png)

[**AFTER EXPANDING the accordion:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NZZq.png)

I have kind of taken the code from primefaces showcase, and didn't touch it much, but anyway here's what is in my xhtml:

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

TABLE CODE:

```
            <p:dataTable id="idDataTable" value="#{analysisBean.listOfSamu}" var="nthSamu" rows="10"
                     paginator="true"
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                     selectionMode="single">
            <p:column headerText="ID" sortBy="#{nthSamu.idSamu}" filterBy="#{nthSamu.idSamu}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{nthSamu.idSamu}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="EJE" sortBy="#{nthSamu.nombre}" filterBy="#{nthSamu.nombre}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{nthSamu.nombre}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="EJE" sortBy="#{nthSamu.primerApellido}" filterBy="#{nthSamu.primerApellido}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{nthSamu.primerApellido}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="IM" sortBy="#{nthSamu.importe}" filterBy="#{nthSamu.importe}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{nthSamu.importe}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="FE" sortBy="#{nthSamu.fecha}" filterBy="#{nthSamu.fecha}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{nthSamu.fecha}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

ACCORDION CODE:

```
    enter code her <p:fieldset legend="Filtros" style="width: 40%" >
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <p:accordionPanel multiple="true" style="width: 100%">
                        <p:tab title="Acerca del Giro">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="5">
                                <h:column>
                                    <h:outputLabel style="vertical-align:middle" value="Oficina: " />
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="oficinaSelect" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Todos" itemValue="Todos" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="  Naguaes" itemValue="  Naguaes" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="  aguaes" itemValue="  aguaes" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Naguaes" itemValue=" s Naguaes" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="aguaes" itemValue=" s aguaes" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </h:column>
        

                    <h:column>
                                <h:outputLabel style="vertical-align:middle" value="País: "/>
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="paisSelect" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Todos" itemValue="Todos" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Naguaes" itemValue="  Naguaes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="aguaes" itemValue="  aguaes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Naguaes" itemValue=" s Naguaes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="aguaes" itemValue=" s aguaes" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="Acerca del Ejecutor">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="5">

                            <p:graphicImage url="images/usericon.png" width="30" height="30" style="border: 3px solid activecaption"/>
                            <h:column>
                                <h:outputLabel value="Naguaidad:" style="vertical-align:middle"/>
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="idNaguaidadSelect2" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Todos" itemValue="Todos" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="aguaes" itemValue="  Naguaes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="guaes" itemValue="  aguaes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Naguaes" itemValue=" s Naguaes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="aguaes" itemValue=" s aguaes" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <h:outputLabel value=" Porto NInj:" style="vertical-align:middle" />
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="id PortoNInjSelect" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Todos" itemValue="Todos" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="aguaes" itemValue="  Naguaes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="guaes" itemValue="  aguaes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Naguaes" itemValue=" s Naguaes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="aguaes" itemValue=" s aguaes" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <h:outputLabel value="Actividad:" style="vertical-align:middle"/>
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="idActividadSelect" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Todos" itemValue="Todos" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="  Naguaes" itemValue="  Naguaes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="  aguaes" itemValue="  aguaes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel=" s Naguaes" itemValue=" s Naguaes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel=" s aguaes" itemValue=" s aguaes" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:accordionPanel>

                <p:commandButton id="idFiltrarCommandButton2" style="float:right" icon="ui-icon-search" value="Filtrar" action="#{analysisBean.populateList()}" update="idDataTable"></p:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly with prime-faces.  Seems like you need to have the dataTable and the accordionPanel within two seperate forms and panels.  I would recommend doing something like,

Code:

```
    <Dialogue>

      <Form1>
       <Panel>
          Datatable
       </panel>
      </Form1>

      <Form2>
        <panel>
         AccordionPanel
        </panel>
      </Form2>

     </Dialogue>
```

just don't forget to update the respective forms accordingly

Comment: That is not JSF / Faces / PrimeFaces code.